# OpenOfficeXML inserting extra lines into Excel worksheet (X++/C#)

Tags: c#, xml, openoffice.org

I'm using OpenOfficeXML to insert records into an Excel workbook. The process runs fine when the number of inserted records is fewer than 1110 records. If there are more records to insert (1111 or greater), the rest of the Excel worksheet is converted into its XML equivalent (which I do not want). It seems like this is because of some type of leak - any advice?

What shows in the Excel worksheet (XML code):

```
<r xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><t xml:space="preserve">□ </t></r><r xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><rPr><b /><sz val="11" /><color indexed="12" /><rFont val="Arial" /><family val="2" /></rPr><t>Yes</t></r>
```

What it should show in Excel:

□ Yes

Comment: Is a record one row?  I don't have access to the schma to see if there are any limits in the schema.  An excel workbook xls (not xlsx) is limited to 65,000 rows that is why I'm asking the question.

Comment: Yep, one record = one row.  The 65k row limit was my first thought, too, but there are 3k rows in a file, max.

Comment: I can't get to the schema url listed in the file.  Can you get the schema and check if there is any limits.

Comment: Are there any empty rows? I know reading an excel file with empty rows some read methods stop.

Comment: No, there are no limits in the schema. There aren't any empty rows that the process is reading, either. The sharedStrings.xml file is different between the file that looks ok and the file with the above error, though.

Comment: So it is failing at the beginning of a new file that is being imported?  Does file have different number of columns?  Does the line have any special characters (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Comment: It doesn't necessary fail--it just outputs XML code where it's not expected within the Excel worksheet. The file is stored on a server, then the code manipulates it, and exports it (using SaveAs) to the user. The number of columns remains the same, and the line doesn't have any special characters.

Comment: What is first character of the line.  Excel does funny thing if the beginning of a row has numbers verses letters.  It sometimes screws up the file.  What type is the first column?  General, Number, String?

Comment: Why not use a library like EPPlus to generate the sheet? I assume by OpenOfficeXML you actually mean you use the *Open XML SDK*, not the Apache OpenOffice XML format

Comment: First character of the line is 'T' (no single quotes), so just a string. Column type is General. And I am using the EPPLUS library (OfficeOpenXML -- title has a typo, my bad)